# How to write to file slash divided string word by word in Bash

Tags: bash, scripting

I have a string, for example `/sd1/sd2/sd3/`

I want to write it to a file in the next way

```
/sd1
/sd1/sd2
/sd1/sd2/sd3
```

How could I do that?

Note: the length of the string could be different. i.e. /sd1/ or /sd1/sd2/sd3/sd4/sd5/

Comment: See _man dirname_, or, if you want to do it without creating a child process, see the section _Parameter Expansion_ in _man bash_.

Comment: Is there a slash at the end of the string or not?

Comment: @oguzismail yes, there is a slash at the end

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This solution works for me

```
string="/sd1/sd2/sd3/"

IFS='/' read -r -a sds <<< "$string"

tmpsd=""

for (( i=1; i<${#sds[@]}; i++ )); do

  tmpsd="${tmpsd}/${sds[i]}"

  echo ${tmpsd} >> file.txt

done
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Is this an answer or part of the question? Please read [answer].

Comment: @Chris this is the answer

Comment: Then please read [answer], then [edit] the answer and make that as clear as possible.